# ヘルプセンター「良い質問をするには？」末尾のリンク集が一部リンクになっていない

Tags: バグ, 完了

Go to the [Japanese StackOverflow how to ask help center page](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and scroll down to the bottom.

[image: Japanese]

Each bulleted point should lead to a link like it does at the bottom of the [English version](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

[image: English]

Some links are present, some are not.

Answer (score 1):

勘違いしました。英語の記事が残っていると思っていましたが、確認するとリンクになっていない理由はリンク先は英語になります。

そのため、下記の部分を削除しました：

```
<h3>支援を要請して探す</h3>

<p>どんなに努力しても、質問の評価が低いこともあります。がっかりしないでください!よい質問の仕方を学ぶのは価値のあることで、また一夜にしてマスターできるものではありません。役に立ちそうな追加情報を以下に挙げます。</p> 

<ul> 
<li><a href="http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask">質問方法</a></li> 
<li><a href="http://msmvps.com/blogs/jon_skeet/archive/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question.aspx" rel="nofollow">Writing the perfect question</a> (完璧な質問を書く)</li> 
<li><a href="http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/10811/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions">課題の質問と回答を投稿するには?</a></li> 
<li><a href="http://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/" rel="nofollow">How to debug small programs</a> (小規模なプログラムのデバッグ方法)</li>
<li><a href="http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/asking-questions">Meta discussions on asking questions</a> (質問方法に関するメタ ディスカッション)</li> 
<li><a href="http://www.catb.org/~esr/faqs/smart-questions.html" rel="nofollow">How to ask questions the smart way</a> (賢く質問する方法) — 長文ですがよいアドバイスです。</li> 
</ul>
```

もし誰かが上記のリンク先をメタで翻訳したい場合、それへのリンクを追加しますが、とりあえず追加情報がないため、削除します。

Comment: これもrev 2015.4.1.2436で未解決のように見えます。質問が投稿されたのもこの数時間のことですから、恐らく質問者さんと同じ状況なのだと思いますが。

Comment: @unarist 指摘ありがとうございます。更新しました。

Comment: 英語版でリンクされている記事の翻訳だけでなく、同様に参考になる日本語の記事にリンクすることもできるのでしょうか？（http://www.hyuki.com/writing/techask.htmlなど）

Comment: @unarist 追加しました。